# How do I map a socket port between the guest and the host on Parallels?

Tags: socket

I am trying to analyse some client server applications on Mac and Windows and I would like to configure Parallels so it will map a set of ports between the guest and the host.

This would allow me to reffer to the localhost:port on both machines, even if the client is running on Windows guest and the server on the OS X host.

How can I do this? ...and preferably in a persistent way.

Comment: Question on development environments are [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Hmm, I am not so sure what's about development, I think that's the perfect case of question that could have the same rights to reside on any of these 3 SE sites: serverfault, apple and stackoverflow... based on the number after the close link, I guess I picked the worst option regarding willingness to help. "debugging" something does not mean writing code, when your network is down, you may debug the problem... that doesn't make you a developer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I can't give specifics, as I don't have a Parallels instance to refer to at the moment, but you should be able to set the guest's network to NAT, and then specify a set of port forwards between the host and the guest.